# How do I scope my website cookies to a Fully Qualified Domain Name on my PHP web application

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-4

The pent test on our PHP web application yielded a "Loosely Scoped Cookie" alert. The suggested solution is "Always scope cookies to a FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name)."

We used Laravel 4 to build the web application. I inserted a code on the view file, main.blade.php to set the cookie to our domain. The code is listed below:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_domain','johndoe.abc.com'); //johndoe is a sub domain of abc.com
```

After I added the codes, the pent test still yielded the same result. How do I set the scope of my website cookies to the domain?

Comment: In your **.env** file add `SESSION_DOMAIN=example.com`, `APP_URL=http://example.com` and inside `config/session.php` update the **path** key.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. I'll post the results of the pent test.